# For a particular domain, how can I cache its JSON responses locally?

Tags: json, caching, reverse-proxy, breeze

I'm coding the frontend of a web app that uses XHR to grab JSON data from a 3rd party.

The 3rd party service is slow and because of its API design, we need to make a LOT of API requests every time I refresh the page to test some new code. It's making the development loop painful.

The requests are GETs, POSTs and PUTs even though I'm pretty sure none of the requests are changing state.

I want to go to localhost for the JSON rather than to this 3rd party API - simply to make my development process faster.

Comment: This is off-topic, should be on StackOverflow

Comment: You do realise don't you that caching AJAX defeats the purpose? In such a case it would be better to code it statically. "pretty sure none of the requests are changing state" really means you don't know if the state is changing or not, hence should not be cached. It's back to basics for you.

Comment: @John, I see I left out that this is for development only. Caching in my scenario is to speed up development accessing a (slow) API we don't control. As an aside, the insult seems unnecessary.

Comment: @BrentPabst Sorry I was thinking this would be more of a server-based solution (maybe reverse proxy cache or similar) rather than code.

Comment: @Chris, no insult was intended, as I was merely pointing out that you've missed the fundamental principle of AJAX, which is to be dynamic. However, if you feel insulted imagine how we feel every time we see off topic posts. As you have accounts on multiple Stack Exchange sites you should be well aware that you should read the FAQ on each one before participating.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers What I was hoping for or what I had an inkling might be the solution was server software (Squid, nginx or similar). Based on the "if your question is about" and "and it is not about" sections of the faq, I thought I _was_ posting in the right place.

Comment: @Chris, that would make it a shopping question, which is off topic for all SE sites.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers If you say so. I think my problem is specific and answerable as a question, I'm not asking for favorites. I said I suspect the problem might be solvable with a piece of server software in defense of posting here vs. StackOverflow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5856/discussion-between-chris-and-john-gardeniers)

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty basic, utilize a library like AmplifyJS, BreezeJS, or the built-in jQuery options for caching.

Comment: Thanks but it wouldn't make sense to modify our code to support this - my need is more akin to needing mock data or supporting offline operation for development purposes.

Comment: Well if thats the case you should be using mocks anyway instead of calling to the real API, this is one of the problems that mocks are intended to solve. Check this out: http://experiments.mennovanslooten.nl/2010/mockjson/

Comment: mockJSON looks interesting, thanks. I'll have to look at the implementation - it's not even our code that is calling the API, it's a partner-supplied (Javascript) library.

Comment: Sure, theoretically of course you could also setup a simple in-house internet proxy that caches page content as well.  Heck, even Windows can be configured to do this.  Simply setup a dev proxy, force dev users to use it, then when requests for a resource, assuming JSON, are requested the server then requests on the clients behalf and stores the resource for "x" amount of time.  If thats what you really want there are plenty of questions on SF that answer and discuss this question.

Comment: I think that is what I'm after. However my understanding is that most/all off the shelf proxy software doesn't cache PUT/POSTS which makes sense typically but means they won't solve my issue.

Comment: Well that seems right since from a technical viewpoint a put alters data which means that the get should then change as well, invalidating your cache.  A post will update a record, again invalidating your cache. I'm not really sure what you are looking to do with a server cache is a support use case.  The implementation you should take a look is those json mocks to mimic inputs a lot like jsfiddle does.

Comment: Ya I guess I was hoping some drop-in solution existed that I wasn't aware of. Seems like that's not the case. Supposedly the vendor is going to supply us with a version of code that will handle mock data as well so my pain point should go away.